# memcached-1.4.5 compilation problem for mips architecture?

Tags: memcached

I am using memcached-1.4.5 in our project. I am new to this & trying to compile it for **mips** architecture. I am getting below error:

```
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for icc in use... no
checking for Sun cc in use... configure: error: in `$HOME/MEMCACHED':
configure: error: cannot run test program while cross compiling
See `config.log' for more details.
configure memcached failed, bailing out
```

If anybody has encountered such issues can help me out to fix this problem.

Comment: Generally, the more useful information is in the config.log.  It looks like you might have some weird environment variables set up, though.  If you can paste your env and config.log somewhere, it should be easier to understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of bugs in configure.ac for 1.4.5 that prevents you from doing a successful cross compilation. I believe they are fixed in the upcoming engine branch.. you may give that a shot..